# Некоректно работает веб приложение. Не отправляются данные в бд

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Собственно в чём пробелама. Веб приложение на локальном сервере mamp pro работает отлично. Регистрация, изменения данных у уже созданных пользователей, но вот выгрузив приложение на сервер, появилась проблема. Регистрация работает исправно, но обновление данных у уже существующих пользователей работает некоректно. А вернее работает один раз и семи-восьми. Что я имею ввиду: После регистрации у пользователя в бд есть строка как "points". Туда зачисляются баллы за прохождение тестов в приложении. Т.е. человек набрал 4 балла, и эти 4 балла ссумирывались с тем что у него уже есть в бд. Если было 0, то стало 4, а если было 2, то стало 6. Ну вы поняли. Так вот эти баллы не начисляются. Но это если использовать телефон. А вот если запустить приложение на пк, то всё отлично работает. Всё записывается, работает отлично. В чём может быть проблема?

Более кратко: на локальном сервере всё отлично, а на хостинге нормально работает только пк.

Код подключения к бд:

```
<?php   
$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'youthvif_hemika02', '8Au34mFov9', 'youthvif_db');
$mysql->set_charset("utf8");
```

Код отправки данных в бд:

```
<?php

include '../php/connect.php';

$login = $_COOKIE["login"];

$func = $_POST['func'];
if ($func === 'func_data') {
    $arr['newUserPoints'] = $_POST['newUserPoints'];
    $arr['newAllPoints'] = $_POST['newAllPoints'];
    $arr['nameTest'] = $_POST['nameTest'];
    $arr['result'] = $_POST['result'];
    $arr['fulfield'] = $_POST['fulfield'];
    echo json_encode($arr);
}

$userPoints = $arr[newUserPoints];
$allPoints = $arr[newAllPoints];

$nameTest = $arr[nameTest];
$result = $arr[result];
$fulfield = $arr[fulfield];

$mysql->query("UPDATE `users` SET `points` = '$userPoints' WHERE `users`.`login` = '$login'");
$mysql->query("UPDATE `goals` SET `allPoints` = '$allPoints'");

$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `complTest` (`login`, `test`, `points`, `fulfield`) VALUES('$login', '$nameTest', '$result', '$fulfield')");

// setcookie($nameTest, $fulfield, time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, "/");

$mysql->close();
```

Comment: смотри логи хостинга при обращении через телефон.....в логах будут написаны ошибки наверняка..... а можешь и вообще включить отображение ошибок и посмотреть что будет

Comment: небось кук нет на телефоне, не сохраняются

Comment: А как их включить? Ибо в mamp pro есть такая галочка, но где руками включить не знаю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482

Answer (score 0):

А вы пробывали запринтить данные перед передачей в запросе?

```
echo $login;
$mysql->query("UPDATE `users` SET `points` = '$userPoints' WHERE `users`.`login` = '$login'");
```

Учитывая что логин берется из куки, мне кажется проблемма в нем.

- 2 совета исходя из вашего кода.

1. Не используйте mysql, Используйте хотя бы PDO
2. Данные которые лежат в куки, легко модифицируются и могут содержать неожыданное содержание, например команду на удаление бд.
   Вместо `$_COOKIE["login"]` используйте `$_SESSION["login"]`